# Java jTable columns not resizing to fit content at start of app

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Based on https://bosmeeuw.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/java-swing-automatically-resize-table-columns-to-their-contents/
I created a JFrame app that displays a table (jTable).

The data is populated automatically from a file after initComponents() is called.
It is just a display only App.

When App start, it is showing columns at default width with data.

When I double click on any cell and then click on any other cell, the columns resize fine as expected.

I want the app to show the column resized to fit content at startup.

Please help.

Code parts from my class below:

```
public callA() {
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        initComponents();

            readConnectionsXML();

    }
```

jTable declaration:

```
jTable_ConnectionsDetails.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        jTable_ConnectionsDetails.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Connection Name", "Conn Type", "Host", "Port", "Service Name", "User", "profilename", "Password", "desc"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable_ConnectionsDetails.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        jTable_ConnectionsDetails.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                ColumnsAutoSizer.sizeColumnsToFit(jTable_ConnectionsDetails);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane_ConnectionsDataTable.setViewportView(jTable_ConnectionsDetails);
```

Comment: I am adding data as - `ConnectionTablemodel.addRow(new Object[]{Reference_Element.getAttribute("name"), cElement_DBType, cElement_Host, cElement_Port, cElement_DBName, cElement_User, cElement_Password, cElement_Password, cElement_ConnURL});`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    jTable_ConnectionsDetails.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            ColumnsAutoSizer.sizeColumnsToFit(jTable_ConnectionsDetails);
```

Ok, it appears you automatically resize the columns every time the data is changed.

> When I double click on any cell and then click on any other cell, the columns resize fine as expected.

Every time you edit a cell the value is saved and a TableModelEvent is generated to the above code gets executed.

> The data is populated automatically from a file after initComponents() is called.

So did you verify that the listener code from above is executed?

If it is NOT executed, then you need to manually invoked the `ColumnsAutoResizer` method.

If it IS executed then it may be a timing issue because the GUI is not yet visible. Try wrapping the code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` so the code is added to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and it will be executed after the GUI is visible.